# How to program an silent automatic email alter in Android?

Tags: android, email, alert

Sorry, I'm new to Android, so I have a button in my Activity and I want that every time when someone clicks that button, an email will be sent to my email address. I found a couple of email APIs that open the email app of the smartphone but what I want is the that the users clicks the button, a thank you screen will be shown and then it returns to the first screen. Meanwhile I will get the notification via mail. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should user input the message or is the message hardcoded?

Comment: is hardcoded, thanks to Kasra it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GMailSender class as described in [here](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Send-Mail-in-Android-without-Using-Intent).

Answer (score 1):

To send mail in background first you need to get the Oauth code.

Setup the Google developer console, instructions below:

> Obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials
>
> You need OAuth 2.0 credentials, including a client ID and client
>   secret, to authenticate users and gain access to Google's APIs.
>
> To find your project's client ID and client secret, do the following:
>
> Go to the Google Developers Console. Select a project, or create a new
>   one. In the sidebar on the left, expand APIs & auth. Next, click APIs.
>   In the list of APIs, make sure all of the APIs you are using show a
>   status of ON. In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials. If you
>   haven't done so already, create your project's OAuth 2.0 credentials
>   by clicking Create new Client ID, and providing the information needed
>   to create the credentials. Look for the Client ID and Client secret in
>   the table associated with each of your credentials. Note that not all
>   types of credentials use both a client ID and client secret and won't
>   be listed in the table if they are not used.

Refer to the tutorial here for retrieving Oauth token and use in app:

http://blog.tomtasche.at/2013/05/google-oauth-on-android-using.html

In the scope update with these for sending mail:

```
private final String SCOPE = GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE + " " + GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY + " " + GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM;
```

After you retrieve the Oauth use the below code to send mail:

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;
import com.sun.mail.util.BASE64EncoderStream;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.URLName;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

public class GMailSender {
    private Session session;


    public SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host, int port, String userEmail,
                                       String oauthToken, boolean debug) throws Exception {
        Log.v("ranjapp", "came to connecttosmtp");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");
        //props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms.oauth2.oauthToken", oauthToken);
        session = Session.getInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
        SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
        // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
        final String emptyPassword = null;
        transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);
        Log.v("ranjapp", "came before gen response");
        byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", userEmail, oauthToken).getBytes();
        response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);

        Log.v("ranjapp", "came to call issuecommand " + transport.isConnected());
        Log.v("ranjapp", new String(response));

        transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);

        Log.v("ranjapp", "came after issue command");
        return transport;
    }


    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String user,
                                      String oauthToken, String recipients) {
        try {
            SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com", 587, user, oauthToken, true);

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);

            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

            smtpTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ranjith", e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Use the below code to send mail(uses above class):

```
private class senmailAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            GMailSender gMailSender = new GMailSender();
            gMailSender.sendMail("hi", "hi", authPreferences.getUser(), authPreferences.getToken(), whomtosendgmailid);
            Log.v("ranjapp", "sent mail " + authPreferences.getUser() + "  " + authPreferences.getToken());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Call it using:

```
new senmailAsync().execute();
```